# enabledRemoteNotificationTypes returns wrong value on ios 6.0.1 ipod

Tags: ios6, apple-push-notifications, ipod-touch, uiapplication

We are checking to see if APNs are enabled by using the UIApplication's enabledRemoteNotificationTypes method. This works fine for iPhones with iOS 6 and below. However, on an iPod with iOS 6.0.1, the method continues returning 0, indicating that no APN types are enabled, even when APNs have been manually enabled in the iPod's settings.

This occurs after APNs are first manually disabled on the device for this app.

Has anyone else seen this? And do you have any advice as to how to deal with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a good http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: This happens to me too. On an ipod5 as well. ios7.